# Track cellular usage statistics in iOS

Tags: ios, statistics, cellular-network

I want to make an app that displays statistics of cellular usage alike how many calls there where made, for how long each call was, number of text messages, etc...

I can't find any resource anywhere, even not in the Apple Developer documentation.

Is this kind of app possible?
Does anyone know how I can set up this kind of app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API for this information.

In general, the iOS security sandbox blocks an app from gathering any information about any other app, including the Phone app, unless there is a public API, or a previously registered URL handler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't you will be able to access this kind of information. I do think it would be a trivial task in Android, but in iOS I doubt it.